# How to add input files to bazel run in TeamCity

Tags: go, teamcity, bazel

I'm super new to bazel so lots of understanding could be wrong.

I have a local directory with the following structure:

```
/my/certain/path
|- my_test.go
|- my_utils.go
|- BUILD.bazel       
|- mydir 
     |- input1
     |- input2
```

I'm using `bazel run` in TeamCity to run a go test with `my_test.go` (some sensitive info is replaced with `xxx` or `...`):

```
bazel run \
  //my/certain/path:my_test \
  --config=crosslinux --config=test \
  --test_timeout=1800
```

And in the `/my/certain/path/BUILD.bazel` I have

```
go_library(
    name = "path",
    srcs = ["my_utils.go"],
    importpath = "/my/certain/path",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_docker_docker//api/types",
         ...
        "@org_golang_x_net//context",
    ],
)
go_test(
    name = "my_test",
    size = "enormous",
    srcs = ["my_test.go"],
    embed = [":xxx"],
    deps = [
        "//pkg/util/contextutil",
        "//pkg/util/log",
        "@com_github_docker_docker//client",
        "@org_golang_x_net//context",
    ],
)
```

The `my_test.go` actually will use files in `mydir` as input when running.

But when running on teamcity, I notice `mydir` was not mounted in the temporary directory where this bazel test happens, which made `my_test.go` fail.

I tried to solve it by adding these lines to print out the current directory and all files in `my_test.go`:

```
    fmt.Println("==== listing all files in go====")
    err := filepath.Walk(".",
        func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            fmt.Println(path, info.Size())
            return nil
        })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("==== end listing all files in go====")

    ctx := context.Background()
    pwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("cannot get pwd: %v", err))
    }
    fmt.Println("-----pwd:", pwd)
```

And it shows that the

```
    ==== listing all files in go====
17:26:17     . 4096
17:26:17     my_test_ 4096
17:26:17     my_test_/my_test 152
17:26:17     ==== end listing all files in go====
pwd: /home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/xxxxx/execroot/myname/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my/path/my_test_/my_test.runfiles/my/certain/path
```

So my goal is to mount `mydir` to this working dir (`/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/xxxxx/execroot/myname/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my/path/my_test_/my_test.runfiles/my/certain/path`).

I'm not sure if this is a TeamCity specific question or there's a way in bazel to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the `data` entry in the `BUILD.bazel`:

```
go_test(
    name = "my_test",
    size = "enormous",
    srcs = ["my_test.go"],
    embed = [":xxx"],
    data = glob([
            "mydir/**",
    ]),
    deps = [
        "//pkg/util/contextutil",
        "//pkg/util/log",
        "@com_github_docker_docker//client",
        "@org_golang_x_net//context",
    ],
)
```